# How to remove negative outputs from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have used a function to calculate the difference between 2 values. From printing the output of the function below, the answer ranges from -5 to 4. However I only want the function to display positive answers only (i.e: 1 to 4). 
Is it possible to disregard the negative values without changing the boundaries  of x and nor change the value of a?

```
import numpy as np
L = 10 
a = 5

def position(x,a):
        return x-a

x = np.arange(0.0, L, 1)
print (position(x,a))
[-5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
```

Comment: to only keep values satisfying a condition use logical indexing in your example: `y[y > 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
L = 10 
a = 5

def position(x,a):
    return x-a

x = np.arange(0.0, L, 1)
tmp = position(x,a)
print (tmp[tmp>=0])
```

Comment: The OP asked for only positive, so shouldn't it be `> 0`?  (In his "i.e.", I mean-- he was inconsistent elsewhere..)

Comment: @DSM yep, true. And yes, depending on which part of the post to look at, the answer could also be no =)

Answer (score 1):

This may help, an example of filtering a numpy array

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.array([-1.1, 0.0, 1.1])
print(arr)
bools = arr >= 0.0 # define selection
print(bools)
# filter by "bools"
print(arr[bools])
```

Answer (score -1):

based on what I can take from your question this should work:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x:x>=0, position(x,a))
```

Comment: This should work, but is too complicated compared to the other suggestions. Nevertheless it possibly could take less RAM.